# Accessing the member in a struct array in a struct with a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

the title pretty much says it all i have a struct with an array of struct as one of its member and I can't figure out how to access

```
struct Member{
   short x;
...
};

struct List{
   struct Member members[MAX_MEMBER];
...
};
short function(const struct List*n){
 if((n->members[i])->x ...)
...
}
```

I tried somethin like that but it doesn't work.
Thanks for your answer

Comment: You need `.x` instead of `->x`.  `n->members[i]` is a `struct Member`, so you don't need the pointer arrow notation.  And the parentheses are unnecessary too.  If you're perverse enough, you could use `(&n->members[i])->x`, but that is silly.

Answer (score 2):

`n->members` is an array of `struct Member`, not an array of pointers.  Hence `n->members[i]` is a `struct Member`, not a `struct Member *`.  You should therefore access its members using `.` and not `->`. Try:

```
if (n->members[i].x ...)
```